# Code is running but vs code terminal shows syntax error

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter, inline

```
import plotly.express as px
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
```

I imported these libraries and used `%matplotlib inline` . The code runs fine but the terminal in vs code shows the error :

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

[image: This is the image of the code and error]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to use `%matplotlibinline` in VS Code

```
# Suppress matplotlib user warnings
# Necessary for newer version of matplotlib
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category = UserWarning, module = "matplotlib")
#
# Display inline matplotlib plots with IPython
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

Answer (score 0):

`%matplotlib inline` is not a valid python command. This has a specific meaning when used in ipython/jupyter.